# Load json with double quotes rather than single in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a string that initially has double quotes '{"a":"1","b":"2"}'
and need to keep the double quotes for simplicity in my program later.

When doing json.loads the " turn into '
I need a way that will allow me to load the original string and allow me to call ["a"] and return "1" with double quotes not single

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
import json

d = json.loads(s)
print(d["a"])
print(d['a'])
```

## output:

```
1
1
```

as you can see there is no difference if you use `d['a']` or `d["a"]`
`'a'` or `"a"` are  interchangeable, both represent strings

Comment: sorry i meant with the value 1 i want "1" to be returned rather than '1'. For example with a list of urls for them to use "" rather than ''

Comment: there is no difference btw '1' or "1",  also, when you print they will look the same: 1

Comment: with urls as i was converting the string to bytes but i ended up doing a different approach

Comment: so the issue is fixed?

Comment: Yes but i ended up replacing ' with ", i would still like to know if there is a solution to the original as my fix was messy

Comment: can you post all the details and the context in your question ?